# How do I generates SPI core in Qsys?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, fpga, qsys

I having some issues with generating SPI master core in qsys.

I opened a clean design (with no core in it), and added the SPI core to it and exported all of its signals.

[image]

When I tries to generate the design, its gives an error about a missing file - spi_0 
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, it was quit weird. 
Turns out Qsys requires a "clock source" IP core in order to generate the SPI core.
[image]